# Pitch accent difference: 本当だ！ and 本当だよ

Tags: sentence-final-particles, pitch-accent

I was under the impression that 本当 was 平板型: ほんとうだ{LHHHH}. And the exclamation 本当だ seems to follow this. But the addition of よ seems to change this, as I feel like I hear ほんとうだよ{LHHHLL}. Is that correct? And if so does this apply to other locutions?

Examples of 本当だよ: [1](https://youtu.be/y2CyxcpYndk?t=109), [2](https://youtu.be/424nSAfA118?t=380)

Comment: First off, that is not 頭高型, that's 平板型. Second, do you have a clip?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the question. I know that nouns can have different pitch-accent patterns such that they dictate whether the following particle should be high or low - e.g. as described in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwNjFaK4OXY. But だ isn't a particle, so I don't see how that would work here.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie That was a brain fart. I was composing two questions at the same time, and 頭高型 was intended for the other question which I didn't post. Clips included.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It doesn't have to be particles. That video is about the basic difference between 平板型 and 尾高型. And I think they just tell learners it's only particles for simplicity. Also note that だ is **enclitic**, which means it's **phonetically connected** to the previous word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are saying ほんとうだよ{LHHHHL} in both examples, and it sounds natural.

Intonation is extremely important with sentence-ending particles like よ. Different intonations convey completely different messages. When you gently tell someone that something you have just discussed is true, you would keep it high like ほんとうだよ{LHHHHH}.

ほんとうだよ{LHHHLL} sounds like a bit awkward variation of ほんとうだよ{LHHHHL}.

ほんとうだよ{HLLLLL} sounds completely off, by the way.